# program wont compile via Makefile when using ncurses library?

Tags: c, linux, windows, makefile, ncurses

I'm trying to make a program using the ncurses library, but for some reason when I try to compile using my Makefile it says there's an error in the Makefile and all of the functions from ncurses are undefined. I included the library in the main.c file correctly since when I compile using `gcc main.c -lncurses` the program works correctly and doesn't give any errors or say that anything is undefined. I've tried messing around with the Makefile and I can't get it to work properly, does anyone have a solution?

Makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall --std=c99 -g
LDFLAGS = -lncurses
OBJECTS = main.o
ALL: space_invaders
space_invaders: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o space_invaders $(OBJECTS)
main.o: main.c
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.c -o main.o
clean:
        rm space_invaders $(OBJECTS)
```

Output:

gcc -Wall --std=c99 -g   -o space_invaders main.o
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main': /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:9: undefined reference to` initscr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:10: undefined reference to `noecho' /usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:11: undefined reference to` curs_set'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:22: undefined reference to `stdscr' /usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:22: undefined reference to` stdscr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:22: undefined reference to `stdscr' /usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:22: undefined reference to` stdscr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:23: undefined reference to `stdscr' /usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:23: undefined reference to` wclear'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:24: undefined reference to `mvprintw' /usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:25: undefined reference to` stdscr'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/kyle/space_invaders/main.c:25: undefined reference to `wrefresh'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:7: space_invaders] Error 1

Comment: Please do not post code and text output as images - [reasoning](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Copy it as formatted text into the question.

Comment: The makefile defines `LDFLAGS` but never uses it.

Comment: @kaylum where in the makefile would I use it? I tried looking it up and couldn't figure out where it would be used.

Comment: Well, if you build it manually where do you add  that flag? Put it in the place in the Makfile that corresponds to that same command. That is, add it to command that links the final executable.

Comment: @kaylum Thanks, I put it there and it works properly now.

Comment: Glad that worked. Tip: Make has implicit rules that will use `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` in the right way if you write the makefile appropriately. For example, you can completely remove the `space_invaders` and `main.o` rules and simply have `space_invaders: $(OBJECTS)`. Make will know what to do to produce `main.o` and the final `space_invaders` binary.

Comment: @kaylum no it won't be able to build the `space_invaders` binary.  Make knows how to build a binary _foo_ from an object file _foo.o_ so if you had a `space_invaders.o` it would work.  But make doesn't have a rule that will build a binary _foo_ from any random set of object files.  It can build `main.o` from `main.c` by itself though.

Answer (score 1):

`LDFLAGS` is defined but not used. Add it to the rule that links the final executable.

```
space_invaders: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o space_invaders $(OBJECTS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Alternatively the Make implicit rules can be used to simplify the makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall --std=c99 -g
LDFLAGS = -lncurses
OBJECTS = main.o
ALL: space_invaders

space_invaders: $(OBJECTS)

clean:
        rm space_invaders $(OBJECTS)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to specify the `$(LDFLAGS)` variable in the linking command:

```
space_invaders: $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o space_invaders $(OBJECTS)
```

As you probably have seen, the linking command in the output of your run doesn't show the `-lncurses` option, so the library has not been including, making all the calls to library functions to be unresolved.

I don't recommend you to use the alternative given in another answer about using the implicit linking rule, as it is applicable only to GNU make, and so, it is not portable to other make's around.